# Code is not working in IE5. How can I get to work in IE5?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

//The code below will displayed when a timeout is reached.  The blackout page does not work in IE document 5.

```
function queryTimeout() 
{
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var black = document.createElement('div');
        black.setAttribute('style','font-family:arial;position:absolute;' + 
        'left:0;top:0;' + 
        'background-color:black;z-index:10000;min-width:100%;' + 
        'min-height:100%;overflow:hidden');
        fragment.appendChild(black);
        var body = document.body;
        body.appendChild(fragment);


}
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive of what's not working? (Also, my condolences)

Comment: This may help: https://quirksmode.org/dom/core/

Comment: `createDocumentFragment`  isn't supported in IE5. Neither are a bunch of other things here.

Comment: ginny, I think you could put the black DIV without the fragment.

Comment: IE5 had (has o_0?) _really_ buggy CSS. In IE5, you would likely do it via setting `<font color='black' face='arial'>` in order to get a black font with arial. You wouldn't have `document.body` likely (document.all is there though) I recommend checking internet archeology sites (like dynamicdrive) for solutions here

Comment: `black.setAttribute('style'` and `document.createDocumentFragment()` will have to be replaced with alternatives. IE5's setAttribute won't set styles, and createDocumentFragment doesn't exist.

Comment: Ginny, is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you all.  This is the very first time I ever asked a question. I was so surprised when I just got an email and I said 'whats this'.  I am trying the code now w/o fragment and style.